# What automatic script runs with Bourne Shell (/bin/sh) for root?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, script

I want to add some aliases to my OSX command line environment for easier navigation when in the root prompt (`sudo su` to root). On the Bourne Again Shell (/bin/bash), I can edit /var/root/.bash_profile. But with the Bourne Shell (/bin/sh), what script do I edit for that?

Comment: Have you tried creating a new file `.sh_profile`? I don't know whether it'll help but maybe it will. Just a random guess.

Comment: Didn't work. I found the answer and am posting it in a sec.

Comment: Would using `sudo -s` be an option (which would start a root shell with the current value of `$SHELL`)?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/195239/22780) comes close to answering the question, but I need to start using `sudo su -` instead of `sudo su` in order to switch from regular user to root or the `/var/root/.profile` script won't execute.

Now, unless Apple changes this, regular users by default will get the Bash shell, instead of the Bourne shell, which is unlike the root user. So, for those users, simply editing `~/.bash_profile` will work fine.

Comment: I'd like to point out that `/bin/sh` is not the Bourne shell on OS X or any other modern Unix or Unix-like OS. `/bin/sh` is a POSIX compliant shell which the Bourne shell is not. If the aliases exist in your current environment then just use `sudo -s` instead of creating a `.profile` in root's home folder..